# affect a variable with radiobutton

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm new to android, I have a button that is when its clicked it will get the double value from an EditText and show it in a TextView.

Also I have two radio buttons, one is `positive` and other is `negative`, I want when the user toggle the `negative` button to multiply the double by -1, my code is like:

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
    try {
        myDouble = Double.parseDouble((myDoubleEditText.getText().toString()));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a valid Double", LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    myTextView.setText("My Double is",""+myDouble)

}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.positive:
            if (checked)
               myDouble = myDouble;
            break;
        case R.id.negative:
            if (checked)
                myDouble = myDouble * -1;
            break;


    }

}

}
```

Please guide me to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think a better way is to use RadioGroup and set the listener on this to change and update the View accordingly (saves you having 2 or 3 or 4 etc listeners).

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
       switch(checkedId) {
        case R.id.positive:
               myDouble = myDouble;
            break;
        case R.id.negative:
                myDouble = myDouble * -1;
            break;
    }
        }
    });
```